# Azure Functions/Microsoft Graph binding not getting a token (clientCredentials)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I´m trying to use the new Microsoft Graph binding feature on Azure Functions, so I´ve followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph) (using `clientCredentials`):

The Azure AD App has been registered well, however, when calling the Function, I´m getting the following error:

```json
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'ba8b3444-403f-4472-aba3-0407c563dd28' was not found in the directory microsoft.com\r\nTrace ID: 76a06d59-43a5-4862-9a1e-7864121c2200\r\nCorrelation ID: f511ce93-d6e3-40f2-8427-a3af0b89750d\r\nTimestamp: 2017-11-20 10:11:41Z",
    "error_codes": [70001],
    "timestamp": "2017-11-20 10:11:41Z",
    "trace_id": "76a06d59-43a5-4862-9a1e-7864121c2200",
    "correlation_id": "f511ce93-d6e3-40f2-8427-a3af0b89750d"
}
```

As I say, the App Id is correct, and is registered in my Azure AD Directory (with the right permissions). Why is using `microsoft.com` directory when trying to get the Token??!!

This is my function c# code (just returning the Token):

```cs
public static async Task<string> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string graphToken, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return graphToken;
    //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
    //return await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups");
}
```

and here is my _function.json`

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "graphToken",
      "type": "token",
      "direction": "in",
      "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      "identity": "ClientCredentials"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue which we believe to be caused by the binding using the common endpoint as opposed to a dedicated tenant. I'm not sure why the default behavior with the common endpoint is to use the Microsoft tenant, but I can reproduce the issue in any tenant by performing the flow manually against the common endpoint.

I just realized the issue wasn't tracked on our GitHub repo, so I've created a new item: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/issues/25

No ETA on the fix, but the team will be working on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. Good to see the code is already fixed and waiting for the next release. Also mention that, as a workaround, you can get the app token using ADAL/MSAL as usual, and it works fine from the Azure Function. Thanks again!